# Prove or disprove $n! \in O(n^{n-2})$

Tags: limits, asymptotics

Prove or disprove $n! \in O(n^{n-2})$

I think that the statement is true so I tried calculating the limit.

So I have to calculate the limit.

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n!}{n^{n-2}}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n!n^2}{n^{n}}$$

After that i tried substituting Stirlings approximation but it didn't end well. Could I please get some help?

Comment: Do you know or are allowed to use Stirling's approximation? (It's not necessary, but makes things straightforward)

Comment: I dont think im allowed but i tried it anyway

Comment: With Stirling, you are left with the limit of $$\sqrt{2\pi} \frac{\sqrt{n} n^2 n^n}{e^n n^n} = \sqrt{2\pi} \frac{n^{3/2}}{e^n} 
$$so what "didn't end well"?

Comment: You do not really need the full power of Stirling's approximation to prove $n!\leq\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\cdot n$, which is already enough to provide an affirmative answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $$\frac{n!}{n^n}=(\frac{1}{n})(\frac{2}{n})(\frac{3}{n})\cdots (\frac{n}{n})\leq (\frac{1}{n})(\frac{2}{n}))=\frac{2}{n^2}$$

since each term $\frac{i}{n}\leq 1$ for $1\leq i \leq n$.

So $$n! \leq 2n^{n-2}$$

and your statement follows. (Thanks to user  Clement. C for all their help editing this answer =) )

Comment: @ClementC. Whoops, that was supposed to be a 2. Fixed, thank you.

Comment: This is basically the same as in my answer; but with the extra "for large enough $n$ (which has no reason to be there, as it holds for all $n\geq 1$)

Comment: @ClementC. You are correct. Let me edit it again. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

*Most direct proof I can think of:*

Write
$$
n! = \Pi_{k=1}^n k = 1\cdot 2 \cdot \Pi_{k=3}^n k \leq 1\cdot 2 \cdot \Pi_{k=3}^n n = 2n^{n-2}
$$

Can you conclude?

Comment: I was kind of trying to solve it with a limit instead of the definition of O

Answer (score 1):

By ratio test

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+1)!(n+1)^2}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\cdot\frac{n^n}{n!n^2}=\frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n=\frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2}\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}\to \frac1e<1$$

then $$a_n\to 0$$

Answer (score 0):

$n^{n-2}$ is the number of spanning trees of $n$ vertices, and $\frac{n!}{2}$ is the number of ways you can label the linear graph with $n$-vertices by numbers $\{1, \cdots, n\}$, each number being used only once. So $n! = O(n^{n-2})$.

Answer (score 0):

A small improvement: $n!=o(n^{n-2})$.

Set $k:=\lfloor n/2\rfloor$. Then
\begin{align}
n! &\le (2k+1)!=k\prod_{i=1}^k (k+1+i)(k+1-i) \\
&\le (k+1)\prod_{i=1}^k (k+1)^2 = (k+1)^{2k+1} \le \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^{n+1}.
\end{align}
Hence
$$
\frac{n!}{n^{n-2}} \le \frac{\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^{n+1}}{n^{n-2}} \le \frac{(2n/3)^{3n/2}}{n^{n-2}} \le \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{3n/2}n^{\frac{n}{2}-2} \to 0.
$$